# Techniques for keeping Websocket connections alive during depoys/crash

Tags: websocket, socket.io, load-balancing

I have a websocket base web app which I am often hesitant to deploy to as a deploy will kill all connections forcing the clients to reconnect. I currently don't have a nice offline sync feature built in but I would still rather not rely on this.

For deploys I was planning on looking at [hipache](https://github.com/dotcloud/hipache) and pulling a server out of rotation when while it gets updated.This doesn't deal with the situation that one of the server instances crashes while their are still others up and running.

Are their any proven techniques are their for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to listen for `error` or `close` events on the client side and restart the socket as needed. Would that solve your problems?

Comment: I am not concerned about the restart of the sockets but the entire socket server, especially unplanned application restarts which you cannot listen for.

Comment: Seems to me like `error` and `close` events will certainly be emitted on the client side if there's an unplanned outage on the server side. So just have the clients do slightly randomized exponential backoff to try reconnecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kaazing to deploy socket.io in a scalable way. The clustering supported with Kaazing allows you to hot swap gateways in and out of the cluster. Some of our customers configure clustered double dmzs to manage deployments. The best part of this setup is that it allows for any of the gateways to be redeployed with clients gracefully attempting to connect to the currently available connection path. This is both secure and very scalable.

The added benefit is that if you switch the transport for socket.IO to just websocket, Kaazing takes care of the emulation as well, going a bit further than socket.io in providing emulation that doesn't rely on any sort of polling and providing emulation all the way back to even Internet Explorer version 6.

When it comes to high volume production, it's better to have the clustering and load balancing taken care of in a robust way.

If you decide to try this out, make sure to change the socket.io transport to use ws and run it on top of the Kaazing library in the client. On the server side, all you need to do is to proxy the connections to Node.JS. It's possible to write additional adaptors to leverage a broker and socket.IO to get even more load balancing behind each gateway, so multiple nodes can round robin connections on a given gateway.